# Problems with configuring Lando on Fedora (on Linode) to port 80

Tags: proxy, fedora, linode, lando

I have been trying to configure lando to expose my container to public domain that is pointing there. So my domain, lets call it my_app.com, is showing The random port assignments to the container work from the domain but not I am not able to fix it to port 80.

For example Lando starts up and shows these available URLs
 APPSERVER URLS  https://localhost:32781
                 http://localhost:32782
                 http://my_app.lndo.site
                 https://my_app.lndo.site

When I navigate to my domain, my_app.com, it doesn't' work, but if I use my_app.com:32781, it does.

I feel like I am missing something simple. The server itself is a fresh installation of Fedora 29 with Lando v3.0.0-rc.8

My Lando file:

```
name: my_app
recipe: drupal8
config:
  webroot: ./drupal/web
  php: 7.2
  port: '8080'
  drush: ^9
  xdebug: false
event:
  post-rebuild:
    - composer install -d=./drupal
```

Answer (score 2):

Per https://docs.devwithlando.io/config/proxy.html, adding the following lines to your .lando.yml should configure Lando to properly route your custom domain. Port 80 will be bound automatically unless some other service on your machine is already using the port.

```
proxy:
  appserver:
    - my_app.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention a .com domain. Apparently you want your app to be publicly (WAN) accessible. Are you behind any router? Then simply open a port and direct it to your computer IP and your 32782 for http which is port 80 for the outside world. In some routers this is called "Port mapping". [image]

The firewall on your computer needs to have the port 32782 opened. You might need to [include share](https://docs.devwithlando.io/cli/share.html).